# how to append of merge two array of objects in type script

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i am having two array object as follows. This to be done in a loop using typescript. The both objects are dinamically generated from sql api and filtered

**Array of Object 1**

```
customers = [
              {
                id = '1',
                name = 'John',
                engg_id = '6'
              },
              {
                id = '2',
                name = 'Max',
                engg_id = '5'
              },
              {
                id = '3',
                name = 'Rob',
                engg_id = '6'
              },
              {
                id = '4',
                name = 'Rob',
                engg_id = '6'
              }
            ]
```

**Array of Object 1**

```
enggNames = [
              {
                engg_name = 'Surya'
              },
              {
                engg_name  = 'Syed'
              },
              {
                engg_name  = 'Surya'
              },
              {
                engg_name  = 'Surya'
              }
            ]
```

the above array of object to get append to the customers array of objects as below.

**Required Array of Objects**

```
customers = [
              {
                id = '1',
                name = 'John',
                engg_id = '6'
                engg_name  = 'Surya'
              },
              {
                id = '1',
                name = 'John',
                engg_id = '6'
                engg_name  = 'Syed'
              },
              {
                id = '1',
                name = 'John',
                engg_id = '6'
                engg_name  = 'Surya'
              },
              {
                id = '1',
                name = 'John',
                engg_id = '6'
                engg_name  = 'Surya'
              }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your two arrays in the same time and spread values in your results array:

```
const merge = []

for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
  merge.push({
    ...customers[i],
    ...enggNames[i]
  })
}
```

See this working on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ubx74q?file=index.ts).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
customers = customers.map( (customer, index) => {
               customer.engg_name = enggNames[index].engg_name;
               return customer;
            });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your data and use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge properties form multiple objects.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: '1', name: 'John', engg_id: '6' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Max', engg_id: '5' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Rob', engg_id: '6' },
  { id: '4', name: 'Rob', engg_id: '6' }
];

const arr2 = [
  { engg_name: 'Surya' },
  { engg_name: 'Syed' },
  { engg_name: 'Surya' },
  { engg_name: 'Surya' }
];
            
const merge = (a1, a2) => a1.map((o, i) => Object.assign({}, o, a2[i]));

console.log(merge(arr1, arr2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```